# How does exactly tensorflow calculate gradients?

Tags: tensorflow, deep-learning

I went through the optimizer class in tf. From there I am clear that how tf calculate analytical gradients.

Also I found something related to gating gradients and parallel calculation of gradients.
What are these things?

Comment: it uses reverse mode automatic differentiation. It's in gradients_impl.py

Comment: Yeah I went through. So we need back propagation if we calculate analytical gradients right ? But here we don't need such operation right.

Comment: Sorry, don't know what analytical gradients are. Reverse mode AD is another name for backpropagation, which is what TensorFlow uses

Comment: Analytical means calculating grads with back propagation by getting derivatives.

Comment: TF does calculate analytical gradients, what makes you think it does not? The representation is fully symbolic. I am not sure what are you expecting?

Comment: Yeah. I edited the question. Yes it calculated analytical gradients. I went through it. But how do they do backprop? It's like for each operation they have implemented the differentiation? For example cross entropy , batch normalization etc ?

Comment: Secion 4.1 in TensorFlow white paper would be a good starting point.

Comment: Another thing, Tf caluclate the gradietns when we run the optimizer().minimize(loss) in a session. So what if our loss model is a recurrent neural net. is there any implementation on back prop through time.